# Azure Mobile Services Custom Identity Provider from Javascript App

Tags: azure-mobile-services

I am trying to implement a custom identity provider in Azure Mobile services and I am using an HTML5/JS app to consume it. I am following [Josh Twists post on the matter](http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Exploring_custom_identity_in_Mobile_Services_Day_12_.aspx) and I have it set up per his instructions. His blog post consumes the new identity table via objC.

I'm *very* new to this so please bear with me if it's something mundane that I missed. I apologize in advance.

I have successfully consumed other tables in the AMS using JS but this one is returning a Server 500 error. I have updated the Master Key with my own. And added the accounts table and the script he specifies on the insert function for that table.

Here's the JS I am using to try to call the table:

```
var item = {
        username: $("#username").val(),
        passowrd: $("#password").val(),
        salt: "1234",
        login: true
    };
    client.getTable("accounts").insert(item);
```

In this case client is my MobileServiceClient and I use the same client.getTable("").insert(obj) to insert into other tables and it works just fine.

One thing I do notice in the insert script I got from the blog is that it says there's an unexpected use of |= and ^.

```
function slowEquals(a, b) {
var diff = a.length ^ b.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length && i < b.length; i++) {
        diff |= (a[i] ^ b[i]);
    }
    return diff === 0;
}
```

If anyone could help me understand where I am going wrong I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you for taking the time to read this.

EDIT: Thanks Josh. Didn't realize the logs were there. Ended up being an issue of not getting length of undefined... it was undefined because I passed passowrd instead of password. Thanks for your quick help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked the logs (in the management portal) for details of the 500 error? Also, I have a web implementation here - http://doto.mobi/web (it's the web version of http://doto.mobi).

You can view source and see that it uses custom identity. It's not exactly the same backend but pretty close, should be a good head start.